# Unable to pass down useState props for adding count

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, use-state

I have three components im trying to connect together to add the number of items I have in a shopping cart. I have the main component which creates the CartCount object and setCartCount functionality:

```
function MinerStore() {
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState([0]);

  const addToCart = () => {
    setCartCount(cartCount + 1);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div >
        <StoreNav cartCount={cartCount} />
        <div>
            <StoreCard addToCart={addToCart} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I also then have the two components I am trying to show the added count on as well as the added count functionality:

```
export default function StoreCard(addToCart) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <main>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {data.map((data) => (
              <Grid item key={data.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
                <Card>
                  <CardContent>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    <div>
                      <Button onClick={addToCart}>
                        Add to Cart
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </main>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```
export default function StoreNav(cartCount) {
  return (
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton>
              <Badge badgeContent={cartCount} color="primary">
                <ShoppingCartIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Comment: When you pass props to a component, the props are combined to a single object. Get the specific property using destructuring - `function StoreCard({ addToCart })`.

Comment: Similar question I answered not too long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055796/3084820

Answer (score 0):

You've set your initial state as an array [0].
Set it as as 0 and check it out
And ofc as the people above mentioned you should either use `props` or `{addToCart}` in the child's parameter.
Then on button should look as such:

`<Button onClick={addToCart /* or props.addToCart */}>Add to Cart </Button>`